# Where should I place a license?

Tags: licensing, teamwork

I'm creating a site for commercial needs, for myself or for sales. In them, I'll use the Laravel framework. Laravel is licensed under the MIT license. The MIT license tells to me:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

What is the meaning of this?

In my opinion, I must include the notice into the chapter "About" and write "The site was created with framework Laravel, Copyright Taylor Otwell...", like in mobile or other apps. But I've never seen this on any website.

Tell me, please, how can I legally fulfill this condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In my opinion I must include the notice into the chapter "About" and write "The site was created with framework Laravel Copyright Taylor Otwell..."

Well, your site delivers HTML and JS to your user's browser, right? So it does not deliver anything substantial from the Laravel framework itself, which is AFAIK written in PHP. However, substantial portions of Laravel are installed *on the server*, right?  So there is the place where you have to put the MIT license file.

It does not hurt if you mention Laravel on some "about" page of the site, to give Laravel a little bit of free advertising if you like, but AFAIK that is not mandatory to fulfill the license terms.

Comment: You mean do I have to upload the file with license of Laravel to folder on server and that's all? And will It be enough for implementation of the license terms?

Comment: @Junior: well, this is what I can tell you for free, being "a stranger from the internet". If you want a warranty on this, ask a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me to understand some important questions which i don't wrote here. I just begin to learn a license question. Don't judge hard. :)